# Failed to install package python-ldap

Tags: python, odoo-15

I am installing package for odoo15 on windows 11, when i install python-ldap package 3.4.0, I am getting an error and I tried to upgrade pip to the latest version but I can't install it. Can anyone help me install ?

[image: Example Image]

I tried very hard but I can't install ldap package on windows 11

Answer (score 0):

As per [python-ldap](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.4.0/installing.html#windows) documentation, there is Unofficial package for Windows are available on [Christoph Gohlke’s page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap).

You can download `.whl` package file for your python version and then install it as below:

`pip install path_to_downloaded_whl/file_name.whl`